# What are "Equivalent Logic Elements"?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga

I'm browsing through the specs of Arista's [Stratix V FPGAs](http://www.altera.co.uk/devices/fpga/stratix-fpgas/stratix-v/overview/stxv-overview.html). The first row of Table 1 is labelled "Equivalent LEs".

What are "equivalent logic elements"? What "logic element" do they use as a baseline? I'm assuming the number given is computed from the number of Adaptive logic modules (ALMs) and the number of registers. Is that correct? What is the formula?

Comment: Marketing term. Much like 3(=2.2)GHz processors.

Comment: What do you mean 3(=2.2)GHz? Are they artificially bumping up the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a term used to try to bridge the world from ASIC & discrete logic to how FPGA function with their slices and lookup tables.
One slice could be used to create a single AND gate or a to some extent part of a larger adder. By rationalising the equivalent logical gates required is some pseudo way of marketing their size.